# Failed to load resource: Observable.js.map in Safari 9.1.2

Tags: angular, angular-cli, rxjs5, angular2-observables

I'm using observables in Angular 2 final with Angular-cli.

- Angular 2.0.0 final
- angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.15
- node: 6.3.0
- Mac os: el capitan

Dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "chart.js": "^2.2.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "d3": "^4.2.3",
    "d3-tip": "^0.7.1",
    "ionicons": "^3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  }
```

My app works fine in every browser except in Safari 9.1.2 – it throws this error message to console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:4200/Observable.js.map
```

I've tried to import Rxjs in angular_cli.json:

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js"
      ],
```

Also, I've tried to import rxjs to app.module.ts and to working component like this:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

But keep getting the same error.

Am I doing something wrong?
It's very strange that only Safari encounters this error.

Comment: I have the same problem in Ionic app running on ios 8.3, have you solved this yet?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sourceMap flag in to True from false in your tsconfig.json file.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
 ///////////////////////
    "sourceMap": true,
////////////////////////

}
```

Because same problem I faced and after that I working fine :)